# Extract value from an array of objects in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb,
I'm trying to extract expectedDeliveryTime from the following data:

```json
        {
          "from": "Giza",
          "delivery_rule": [
            {
              "to": "Giza",
              "expectedDeliveryTime": 3
            },
            {
              "to": "Riyadh",
              "expectedDeliveryTime": 2
            }
          ]
        }
```

I am trying to fetch expectedDeliveryTime WHERE from='Giza' and to='Riyadh'
MySQL equivalent would be SELECT expectedDeliveryTime FROM delivery_rules AS d WHERE d.from='Giza' AND d.to='Giza'

Below is part of my code

```js
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'Setting',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: { $eq: ['$name', 'delivery_rules'] },
              },
            }
          ],
          as: 'delivery_rules',
        }
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          delivery_rules: "$delivery_rules.value"
        }
      },
      { $unwind: '$delivery_rules' },
      {
        $addFields: {
          delivery_rules: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$delivery_rules",
              as: "rule",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$rule.from",
                  "Giza"
                ]
              },
              
            }
          }
        }
      },
 {
$group: {
          expectedDeliveryTime: { $first: '$delivery_rules' },
 }
},
{
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          expectedDeliveryTime: 1,
       }
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pH3SYgifhUp) what you are looking for?

Comment: This brings me closer to the answer. I want the value of expectedDeliveryTime only instead of the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using simply `$match` and `$unwind`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "from": "Giza"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$delivery_rule"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "delivery_rule.to": "Riyadh"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      expectedDeliveryTime: "$delivery_rule.expectedDeliveryTime"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qzXaRH3i9tO) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you, 

I'm getting the value after addFields, how can I match and unwind after addFields:
      {
        $addFields: {
          delivery_rules: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$delivery_rules",
              as: "rule",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$rule.from",
                  "$seller.address.city"
                ]
              },
              
            }
          }
        }
      }

Comment: @AmosEvange I am not sure if you need that anymore. the result is already filtered with `from: "Giza"` already. Or if you have some form of expected output, you can update your question with it and I can update the answer accordingly.